# Auto generate CSS classes from HTML elements style attribute

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was wondering if there's an online software or a script that could auto-generate CSS classes from HTML elements style attribute? Something like checking all style attributes and generate a CSS style sheet from what has been found.

I would like to have something like this:

```
<!-- <div style="margin-top:10px; width:200px; height:100px; 
background:#ddd; border:4px solid #09f;"></div> -->
<div class="s1 s2 s3"></div>

<!-- <div style="margin-top:10px; width:180px; height:100px; 
background:#ddd; border:4px dotted #f00;"></div> -->
<div class="s2 s4 s5"></div>

<!-- <div style="margin-top:20px; width:20px; height:20px; 
border-radius:50%; background:#444;"></div> -->
<div class="s6 s7 s8"></div>

<!-- <div style="margin-top:10px; width:20px; height:20px; 
border-radius:50%; background:#3b3;"></div> -->
<div class="s0 s7 s9"></div>
```

JSFiddle :

[**BEFORE**](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/osLuad7a/4/)

[**AFTER** (with the style sheet)](http://jsfiddle.net/pmrotule/osLuad7a/2/)

---

I know that you can get the style array like this:

```
console.log(document.getElementById('yourElement').style);
```

But how do you compare it with other elements?

Comment: The style attribute overrides any CSS, and it does the same thing. Use CSS instead. You could have your CSS set up already and change your `Element.className` in JavaScript to affect your HTML `class` attribute.

Comment: I mean a script to copy/paste my html code inside a textarea, push a button like "generate style sheet" which will create the style sheet and remove the style attributes. Then I copy the code generated and save it as the new file.

Comment: You would need to use a Server Language like PHP for that. It is doable. There are Content Management Systems for that type of thing already.

Comment: You will find that there's a lot of leeway in "generate a stylesheet". A trivial approach would put a unique random identifier classname on every node and just copy the content of the style attribute to a rule `.(UID) { contents of style attribute here}`, but that's not helpful in a maintainable way.